Filament - FullCalendar Filters
I'm using Filament v3 and I installed the FullCalendar plugin.
Exists a way to add an input filter in the top of the plugin and filter events with the value of that input?
I search in docs, internet but I don't find nothing similar.
Thanks!

You should check Laravel Daily's video on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqcVWk2IR8k
